# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error in localhost?

Tags: php, angularjs, http

I already added this header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); in my PHP, but I'm still getting

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My angularjs POST as below:

```
$http({
        url: 'http://example.com/url/',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'myParam' : 'test' }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            alert('success');
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed
        }
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't depends on Angular. This error depends on the serverrespsonse only.

Comment: Are you posting to `localhost:8100`? In your code you show `http://example.com/url/`?

Comment: @fdomig I do development in localhost..

Comment: @Apédémak Any idea why is it error?

Comment: Sure you do, but the values differ. Show the exact code you are using please.

Comment: Can you show us the code in wich you put this header ? Cuz if there is something wrong, it's here and not in Angular.

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools. Check the Net tab. Check that you are making a POST request. Check that the response actually includes the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but in .NET you have to set some attributes on you API's methods to enable CORS. That might be your problem aswell

Comment: What PHP did you add that code to? PHP at `http://localhost:8100` or PHP at `http://example.com/url/`?

Comment: @Quentin to myAPI.php of course.

Comment: @JamesLemon — Neither of those two URLs includes the string `myAPI.php` so I can't tell which you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add this two line of code via setting the crossdomain to true and cache to false.

```
crossDomain: true,
cache:false,
```

hence your full code becomes

```
$http({
        url: 'http://example.com/url/',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'myParam' : 'test' },
        crossDomain: true,
        cache:false
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            alert('success');
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed
        }
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

It's a bug in Chrome for local dev. Try another browser. Then it'll work.

Comment: so solution for that? how come?

Comment: set default header in run